# C# An object reference is required for the nonstatic field

Tags: c#, wpf, static

**I've already checked similar questions like**

> [CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'foo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/498400/cs0120-an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-prop)
>
> [An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40145070/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property)
>
> [an object reference is required for the nonstatic field method or property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735880/an-object-reference-is-required-for-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property)

I have the following code in a Window:

```
public partial class RegistrationWindow : Window
{
    ...
    ...

    public RegistrationWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Loaded += Init;
    }

    private void Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegistrationFunctions.GotoStep(this, 1); // <-- here the error occurs
    }

}
```

and I have the following class:

```
public class RegistrationFunctions
{
    public void GotoStep(RegistrationWindow window, int step)
    {
         ...
         ...
    }
}
```

I'm not using any `static` class or method, but I'm still getting the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property...

Why am I getting this error even when I don't have anything `static` ??

Comment: The problem *is* that nothing is `static`. `RegistrationFunctions` and/or `GotoStep` have to be `static`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto can you explain ?

Comment: @mrid: On what object reference are you calling the method `GotoStep()`?  It's a non-static method and you're trying to call it as a static method.

Comment: You need an `Instance` of a `RegistrationFunctions` and call the `Method` from there. Something like `RegistrationFunctions rf = new RegistrationFunctions();` and `rf.GotoStep(this, 1);`

Comment: Stated another way, `RegistrationFunctions.GotoStep(...)` is how to call `GotoStep(...)` assuming it is a static method of it's parent class, but it is not a static method in `RegistrationFunctions` as you have it defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why am I getting this error even when I don't have anything `static`?

You're getting this error *because* you don't have anything `static`.  You're trying to use a `static` method that you've defined as an instance method.  Right here:

```
RegistrationFunctions.GotoStep(this, 1);
```

You're not invoking it from an instance, you're trying to statically invoke it from the class.  You have two options:

You can make it static:

```
public static void GotoStep(RegistrationWindow window, int step)
{
     //...
}
```

**or** you can create an instance of your class and call the method on that instance:

```
var functions = new RegistrationFunctions();
functions.GotoStep(this, 1);
```

Which way is correct is really up to you as you define the semantics of your program and decide what makes sense to be static and what doesn't.

Comment: Oh I get it. I'm trying to c class function without initializing the class.